# Add to cart function not working for first product when cart is empty

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using `WC()->cart->add_to_cart($new_post_id);` to add a product ,but this function does not adding for the first time when cart is empty.

If I add product using default add to cart button, Then after the above function works properly so can you please point out the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Quantity is missing of the product try to use

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $new_post_id , $qty );
```

where $qty is a number of items you want to add in the cart for a particular product.
hope this will help you.
Thank you.

Comment: The default qty is 1 as in the method signature: `add_to_cart( integer $product_id = 0, integer $quantity = 1, integer $variation_id = 0, array $variation = array(), array $cart_item_data = array()  )` (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)